# Quitting from j2ee program without using System.quit or return

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have a code block as follows

```
    public Message functionName()
    {
    ...
    try
    {
     Message message;
    //something
    }
    catch
    {
    ...

    // quit here
    }
     return message
    }
```

After throwing exception from the catch block I want to stop further execution. I cannot use `System.quit()` since it kills the server. I cannot use `return 1;` since it is expecting the return type to be of type class. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? end the session? log out the user?

Comment: But if you don't care about what it return can't you  just return a `new Message()` ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context (and also on the API contract).

If the `Message` is something to be displayed/logged (i.e. just a "wrapper" around some text information), I would return new `Message` with the error message from the `Exception` caught in the `catch` block.

Otherwise you can `return null;` (although it is considered to be not-the-best practice), or throw an exception - either the original one, or a new one, with an appropriate message (and, alternatively, the original one as the root cause).